# What does it mean by the last dash in $(gcc -xc++ -E -v -)?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, compiler-options

I often use the command `gcc -xc++ -E -v -` to check the system standard library's include paths. However, I don't understand what the last dash means.

So, my question is:

**What does it mean by the last dash in `gcc -xc++ -E -v -`?**